# Reload <script> attributes on ajax site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the problem:

I have AJAX site that replaces #content block on page load and this pay system JS + HTML

```
<script src = "URL" attrname = "somename" attrprice = "somevalue"></script>
```

After first page loading everything is fine, but if load this page again (with different script attribute values ) i will get old attribute values from the first time.

JS gets attr. values using

```
this.script.getAttribute("attr_name")
```

What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you verify for certain that the page is really being re-sent with the new attribute values? You can view the unmodified DOM, as the server sent it, with Ctrl-U (on Windows)

Comment: Why is your script fetching attribute values? Are you trying to pass arguments to it's functions?

Comment: Are you sure the HTML page is not cached?

Comment: I replace content div with new data. So in DOM i have <script> with new attributes.

Comment: This is the easiest way to see it. Remove script from DOM - ff() function wont stop working. <script type="text/javascript" src="jss.js" ></script>
<div onclick = "ff()"></div>

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be your problem... Why does attr_name have an underscore in the script, and not in the markup?

Comment: The problem is only with ajax sites. I have the same ps on the simple site and it works fine.